# Winform usercontrol in WebForm

Tags: webforms, controls

I want to display a "folderview" which I can drag and drop files into but via WebForm. I am doing this via a webbrowser control pointing at local drive. The code works in a win form user control but what I want is to embed this control in web form. This is an intranet so security etc is less of an issue. However when I add things like AllowDrop or the webbrowser control to my control it stops working - I get the image placeholder which I take to mean an error. Can anyone give me an idea what is wrong or perhaps suggest a different solution.

Comment: Hi I think I have solved part of the problem. If the user control is bigger than the width of the object tag you get the image placeholder. Now it displays all the controls except the webbrowser which is a blank white area.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured it out when you deploy a new version of your user control you need to clear the GAC download cache - gacutil /clc but I think versioning your dll may work. I don't think web browser control work at all but I may be wrong. I've managed to drag and drop msg files with Outlook Automation see http://bytes.com/groups/net-vb/527320-drag-drop-outlook-vb-net-richtextbox